# Is it safe or advised to use dynamic attribute with python?

Tags: python, oop

My question is not really technical. I use a python package with well suited classes which contain numerous attributes and methods. But for my application I would like to store several additional attributes which do not exist in that classes.

Using python, if I set an attribute that does not exist in the class, python just create that attribute. It works. But my question is to know if this is recommended or if I must implement a subclass with that additional attributes ? For example it will allow us to document that new attributes etc ...

Comment: It would be better to derive another class and add the new attributes to the subclass.

Comment: Well, clearly you don't *have* to do it. And clearly you're aware of the consequences and the alternative and what's better about the alternative. So… take your pick.

Comment: If you create a proper subclass, you can i) initialize those attributes to some default so you don't get a NameError if the attribute is not set, ii) you can implement/extend `__eq__`, `__hash__`, `__repr__`, etc. accordingly, taking the new attributes into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sense, this is slightly subjective but there is a clear answer. Do not add new attributes to the original object, create a new class.

I could argue about at least one clear reason for that. A new attribute is making the object do more than it used to do, so it is surely violating the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

So, create a new class to hold this data. Yet, we could give you more information if we actually knew what you are trying to do. So, what about adding some more info?